# Trying to avoid repetition, simplify ... create global variables and simplify my javascript -- pure js no jquery

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object

```
function changeColor() {
    var $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);
    var cp = $('colorPicker');
    var ct = $('col_text');
    var cmess = $('colorMsg');
    var cpback = $('colorPicker_back');
    var rap = $('wrap');
    var newColor = cp.value;
```

//I want to make the above global ... or if there is another way to write this I would love to see.
        $('col_text').style.color = newColor;

```
    if (newColor == "none") {
        ct.innerHTML = "choose";
        cpback.value = "salmon";
        cmess.style.background = "#fff";
        rap.style.background = "#ddd";
        return this;
    } else if (newColor == "yellow") {
        ct.innerHTML = "yellow";
        cpback.value = "salmon";
        cmess.style.background = "salmon";
        rap.style.background = "#ccc";

        return this;
    } else if (newColor == "red") {
        ct.innerHTML = "red";
        cpback.value = "yellow";
        cmess.style.background = "yellow";
        rap.style.background = "#eee";
        return this;
    } else if (newColor == "white") {
        ct.innerHTML = "white";
        cpback.value = "violet";
        cmess.style.background = "violet";
        rap.style.background = "#ea0";
        return this;
    }
}

function changeBack() {

    var backgrnd = document.getElementById('colorPicker_back').value;
    document.getElementById('colorMsg').style.background = backgrnd;

    if (backgrnd == "none")

    {
        document.getElementById('col_text').style.color = "#000";
        document.getElementById('col_text').innerHTML = "choose";
        //document.getElementById('col_text').style.color="white";
        return this;
    } else if (backgrnd == "yellow")

    {

        document.getElementById('col_text').style.color = "red";
        //document.getElementById('col_text').style.color="white";
        return this;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('col_text').innerHTML = "choose";
        return this;
    }
}
```

//This needs to be simplified but I am struggling with how to do it.

Comment: Just move them outside your function and they'll be global?

Comment: @JoeRinehart - Not exactly... it's perfectly reasonable to do what the OP does here, and use `$` as a shorthand for a different approach to similar functionality. I'm not saying it's a Good Idea, as it may confuse other folks who look at your code, but it's certainly not disallowed.

Comment: Heh, I edited my comment - I didn't see the assignment to $ when I originally commented.

Comment: sidenote: totally being pedantic: jquery IS pure javascript.

Comment: on the jquery thing I just meant no shortcuts. I am desperately trying to grasp complex OOP Javasript programming and I have been using Jquery as a crutch for years. I really just want to dig in and full understand how to build strong objects...so this is me learning. Thanks for the help guys I need alot of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $ = document.getElementById;
```

The problem is how you are saving/calling this function.  When a function is called, the value of `this` is set based on how it's called.

`getElementById` expects `this` be `document` (which is set when you do `document.getElementById`).  When you just call `$`, there is no context, so  `getElementById` doesn't work (`this` will be `window`).

Try this instead:

```
var $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

This will force `this` to be `document`.

Comment: Thats great thank you. Another question. How can I make those vars global for both functions AND how come when I try and replace document.getElementById('col_text').innerHTML with ct.innerHTML it doesnt work???

Comment: To make it global, just move the `var $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);` line outside of the function.

Comment: How does it "not work"?  `$('col_text').innerHTML` should work fine.

Comment: When I try to move the vars out of the first function and to the top to work for both functions they cease to work. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?  Are you sure the `$` variable is in the right scope?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would not use $, you are just asking for confusion about what library is in use.

instead of binding, you can just have a function

```
function byId (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Objects are your friend to hold data and avoid nested if. Simple look-up and apply the values.

```
var colorSettings = {
    "none" : {
        "col_text" : "choose",
        "colorPicker_back" : "salmon",
        "colorMsg" : "#fff",
        "wrap" : "#fff"
    },    
    "yellow" : {
        "col_text" : "XXX",
        "colorPicker_back" : "XXX",
        "colorMsg" : "#XXX",
        "wrap" : "#XXX"
    },
    "red" : {
        "col_text" : "YYY",
        "colorPicker_back" : "YYY",
        "colorMsg" : "#YYY",
        "wrap" : "#YYY"
    }    
};
```

and when you apply it, there is no ifs, just setting based on the object

```
function changeColor() {
    var newColor = byId('colorPicker').value;
    var data = colorSettings[newColor];
    byId('col_text').innerHTML = data.col_text;
    byId('colorPicker_back').value = data.colorPicker_back;
    byId('colorMsg').style.background = data.colorMsg;
    byId('wrap').style.background = data.wrap;
}
```

Comment: with this example ... how does it know that colorMsg is an id. Also how does it know that one is the id and one is the hex. I like this way of thinking...looks like json I just don't understand how to fill in the gaps?

Comment: One second. Let me try it before I ask dumb questions.

Comment: I just used the ids of the elements as the name of the property in the object. It can be anything you want, it was just the easiest.

Comment: hmm. trying to understand and I appreciate the help. is this the format you are getting at?    function byId (id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

var data = colorSettings[newColor];
byId('col_text').innerHTML = data.col_text;
byId('colorPicker_back').value = data.colorPicker_back;
byId('colorMsg').style.background = data.colorMsg;
byId('wrap').style.background = data.wrap;

var colorSettings = {
    "none" : {
        "col_text" : "choose",
        "colorPicker_back" : "salmon",
        "colorMsg" : "#fff",
        "wrap" : "#fff";
    },

    "yellow" : { ... },

    }

Comment: I guess what I am saying is total structure of the object is what Im struggling with.

Comment: What is there to struggle? You just copy the none and replace the values for the other colors.

Comment: There was an extra semicolon in my code...is that your issue?

Comment: This is what Im struggling with. Im trying your new way epascarello but its giving me an error. http://jsfiddle.net/6va8t/5/

Comment: well you did not replace the yellow and the red code in the object, of course that is an error.

Comment: Yeah what I meant is you gave me the pieces but I do not know if I am putting it together right. You are dealing with someone with very little OOP experience who is trying to learn. http://jsfiddle.net/6va8t/7/

Comment: It works when you fill in the object: http://jsfiddle.net/cwMtE/ You would just have to deal with none since that is not a color.

Comment: My mind is literally being blown right now. It will take me 5 days to figure this out. Are there any books or articles I can read about taking the complex way of writing that I understand and breaking it down like this?